# Argument of type 'string' is not assignable to parameter of type 'SetStateAction '

Tags: reactjs, typescript

В компоненте React есть функция, которая вызывается при изменении состояния :

```
function handleMove(e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLSelectElement>) {
        setSelected(e.target.value);
        confirmMove(task, e.target.value);
    }
```

В строке setSelected(e.target.value); IDE выдает ошибку

> Argument of type 'string' is not assignable to parameter of type
> 'SetStateAction '.

Во первых, с каких пор в setState нельзя присваивать string?
Во-вторых, я в стейте чётко указал, что стейт может быть типом Property:

```
const [selected, setSelected] = useState<Priority>('none');
```

который, в свою очередь, является типом:

```
export type Priority = 'none' | 'priority1' | 'priority2' | 'priority3' | 'priority4';
```

который может принимать только строковые значения.

Вот как выглядит компонент, из которого приходит value:

```
    const Select: React.FC<ISelectProps> = ({ selected, handleChange, width, height }) => {

    return (
        <StyledSelect
            onChange={handleChange}
            value={selected}
            width={width}
            height={height}
        >
            <optgroup label='Срочность'>
                <option value='none'>Не указывать</option>
                <option value='priority1'>(1) Важная срочная</option>
                <option value='priority2'>(2) Важная несрочная</option>
                <option value='priority3'>(3) Неважная срочная</option>
                <option value='priority4'>(4) Неважная несрочная</option>
            </optgroup>
        </StyledSelect>
    );
};

export default React.memo(Select);
```

Из компонента видно, что значения у selected могут быть только те, которые указаны в типе Priority.

И кстати для этого компонента тоже указан интерфейс для пропс, и в нем тип Priority безотказно работает:

```
export interface ISelectProps {
    selected: Priority;
    handleChange: (e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLSelectElement>) => void;
    width?: string;
    height?: string;
}
```

Comment: тот случай, когда в вопросе содержится ответ :) _с каких пор в setState нельзя присваивать string?_ - _в стейте чётко указал, что стейт может быть типом Property_

Comment: Обрати внимание, что любое значение Property является строкой, но не любая строка, может быть присвоена переменной типа Property.

Comment: @ Grundy см отредактированный вопрос - я добавил компонент с <select>

Comment: суть от этого не поменялась. Тип свойства `value` - это `string`. Чтобы set сработал, тип должен быть `Property`

Comment: @ Grundy он и так Priority! Я же указал тип в useState

Comment: ты путаешь свойство `selected` которое ты передаешь снаружи и которое имеет тип `Property` и свойство `value` которое имеет тип `string`. Обрати внимание на комментарии выше. переменной `string` ты можешь установить значение из переменной `Property`, потому что любое значение из `Property` - это строка. В обратном направлении это не работает. ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: @ Grundy как бы ты это исправил?

Comment: в лоб решение: воспользоваться [Type Assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions) `as Priority`